# where can I find the slider in http://www.pipilika.com/home.php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

what is the name of the slider used under the horizontal menu in
http://www.pipilika.com/home.php
?

where can I find it plz?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check lines 561 to 595 of the source code. The styling will be handled in one of the css files referenced at the top of the source code. (to view the source code right click on the page and select view source). Or enter this in your web browser: view-source:http://www.pipilika.com/home.php

Comment: i pasted the source code in an editor. i think the line numbers u gave are mistaken ones somehow. Any more details on how to implement that plz?